# Flex Event after ADDED_TO_STAGE

Tags: apache-flex, events

Does anyone know if there is any event which is thrown after ADDED_TO_STAGE event for each component?

I am executing some security actions over the components before they are shown (ADDED_TO_STAGE event), but now I need to execute some other actions after this event, but before the components are show.

So, Is it possible? Is there any event thrown in that phase.

thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I beieve ADDED comes after ADDED_TO_STAGE. Be careful, it bubbles, so you need to look at who the target is.

Answer (score 0):

I would give

```
Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED
```

a chance. But you have to remove the event listener after the first dispatch.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, but I think the Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED is only thrown once when the frame is constructed and I need an event which is thrown for each component as the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE...

Comment: Quoting the reference: "Dispatched after the constructors of frame display objects have run but before frame scripts have run."